# A Countdown Timer with reset functionality in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, timer

This works for me, but is this the right way to create this timer?

I might be naive about this but I think this is close to perfect in pure JS.

What would be the drawbacks of using this Timer compared to creating it in a different way?

- Click start and the timer starts to countdown.
- Click reset and the timer resets back to the starting time.

HTML:

```
<button onclick='startStopTimer()'>Start</button>
<button onclick='startStopTimer()'>Reset</button>
<h1>00:10</h1>
```

JavaScript:

```
console.clear()
let timer = document.querySelector('h1')
let startingTime = 9
let startTimer;
let startStopTimer = () => {
  if(startTimer){
    clearInterval(startTimer);
    timer.innerHTML = '00:10'
    startingTime = 9
    return startTimer = undefined
  }else{
    return startTimer = setInterval(()=>{
      timer.innerHTML = `00:0${startingTime--}`
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider the naming `restart` vs `reset`. To me, `reset` means put it back to zero and `restart` means put it back to zero and start the timer again. Could just be me though.

Answer (score 3):

From a short review;

- You use `9` twice, this should be assigned to a nicely named global constant
- You hard code both `9` and `00:10`, this is not flexible. I would expect to be able to change `9` to `99` and to have the timer start at `01:40`
- Similarly, `00:0${startingTime--}` does not allow for much flexibility in the script
- The browser [tries](https://www.goat1000.com/2011/03/23/how-accurate-is-window.setinterval.html) to honor the `1000`, [but it cannot be trusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173580/setinterval-timing-slowly-drifts-away-from-staying-accurate). You are supposed to keep track of the original start and deduct that from current time to determine how much time has passed. Otherwise the timer is not reliable.
- Placing the timer in a `h1` element is probably not a good idea semantically
- Your entire code should be in a well named (self executing) function
- I am not sure why you return anything in `startStopTimer`? If you are never using the returned value, then just drop the `return` keyword
- since `clearInterval` returns `undefined` and because it makes sense, I would go for `startTimer = clearInterval(startTimer);`
- Why `console.clear()`? Production code should avoid `console`

Comment: I thought I was good lol, guess not. Thanks for theses informative gems! Console.clear() is there because I was playing around in codepen. I just copied my whole script. I’ll make sure to keep that out of production code for sure.

Answer (score 3):

#### HTML

- The inline `onClick` event handler attached to your HTML element probably works fine; however there are better ways to deal with the events in pure JS. Next time, add the event handlers in the JS file like so: `element.addEventListener('click', callbackName)`.
- `h1` is a header. I'd not place the timer value inside that particular tag. I think that `span` would be better here according to semantic HTML rules.

#### JavaScript

- Some of your `let`-based variables could be changed to `const`. The idea is to use `const` whenever it's possible. If it's not, only then use `let`.
- `innerHTML` is a dangerous method. It might be used to perform XSS attacks. Try to avoid it to display text on your website.

Comment: Your right I should have used addEventListener for a “pure” js timer. I do need to think about semantics more when I write HTML. It isn’t good practice to not do so. Thanks for that. I should have used innerText instead of innerHTML.

Comment: No problem :) Good luck with refactoring !

Answer (score 2):

### Countdowns

Some points missed or skimmed over by other answers.

- **Visibility:**

  Always keep DOM interaction to a minimum. In timers you should check if the document is visible before you make changes that may not be viewed by the client.

  Timers are one such app that contains animations that the client will not continually watch.

  Use the [page visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) to check for page visibility and listen to visibility change events.
- **Time element:**

  Use appropriate elements. To display a time such as a count down use the [HTMLTimeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTimeElement) and set its [HTMLTimeElement.dateTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTimeElement/dateTime) property to match the visible countdown time.

  This gives meaning to the content and lets machines understand what the content represents.
- **Text is not Markup:**

  Never use [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to set text only content as it will force a CPU/GPU expensive re-flow. Use [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) and avoid the expensive re-flow.
- **Calculate Time**

  Timers such as [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) should not be use to measure time. To measure time till an event store the expected time and calculate the time from now till then.

  Avoid using [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) as it can fire well off the expected interval, rather calculate the time until the next visual change and use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)
- **Scope:**

  Avoid using [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) in the global scope as its scope is un-intuitive and may throw errors due to clashes with existing named variables unrelated to you code.
- **Add don't set listeners:**

  Never set event listeners directly eg `onclick="somefunction"` as the event listener can be overwritten by accident by you, or by poorly written 3rd party code or extensions

  Always use [EventTarget.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)  to add event listeners.
- **Disable unusable UI**

  A button that does nothing should be disabled.

### Rewrite

Following points outlined above the snippet implements a countdown timer with start/restart and stop buttons.

The code details...

- Isolates scope using `{}`
- Calculates timer value rather than count time using timer events
- Calculates time till next visual change rather than use unreliable interval timer.
- Uses the correct element to display time. Also sets the machine readable property `dateTime`. (note that I was lazy and only set the seconds)
- Adds event listeners rather than set event listeners.
- Listens to `visibilityChange` so that the time the client sees is always correct.
- Checks the page visibility before making visual changes to the page. (note the last event will make changes to the DOM)
- Disables the stop button when there is nothing to stop.
- Stores the timer length as the buttons `value` property (Note that the stop button has a value of 0)

```js
{  // to isolate the scope of your code from any existing code.
    const TICK_RESOLUTION = 1000; // in ms
    const TIMER_LENGTH = 10;      // multiples of TICK_RESOLUTION
    startBtn.value = TIMER_LENGTH * TICK_RESOLUTION;
    
    startBtn.addEventListener("click", startStopTimer);
    stopBtn.addEventListener("click", startStopTimer);
    document.addEventListener("visibilityChange", tick);
    
    let endTime, timeHdl;
    function startStopTimer(event) {
        endTime = performance.now() + Number(event.target.value);        
        tick();
    }
    function tick() {
        clearTimeout(timeHdl);
        var till = endTime - performance.now();
        till = till <= 0 ? 0 : till;                
        if (till) {
            if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
                stopBtn.disabled = false;
                timeEl.textContent = (till / TICK_RESOLUTION + 1 | 0);
            }
            timeEl.dateTime = "PT0H0M" + (till / TICK_RESOLUTION + 1 | 0) + "S";
            timeHdl = setTimeout(tick, (till % TICK_RESOLUTION) + 10);
        } else {
            timeEl.dateTime = "PT0H0M0S";
            timeEl.textContent = 0;
            stopBtn.disabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
div {
   font-family: arial;
   font-size: 48px;
}
```

```html
<button id="startBtn" value="0">Start</button>
<button id="stopBtn" disabled value="0">Stop</button>
<div><time id="timeEl" dateTime="PT0H0M0S">0</time> seconds</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I didn’t know about the time element!